# Top 5 Customers in current month (Django)

Tags: python, django, filter

I have an Order model as below:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_date = models.DateField()
    value = models.FloatField(default=0.00)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='orders')
    customer_city = models.ForeignKey(CustomerCity, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='orders_city')
```

I would like to generate a table of Top 5 Customers in current month (based on value of total orders received) in my templates file with ('Customer', 'City', 'Orders Count' and 'Orders Sum') fields.

Was totally confused and clueless about how to get this data. But, tried the following code in my views.py file:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
top_five_customers = Order.objects.filter(order_date__year=today.year, order_date__month=today.month).values('customer').annotate(orders_count=Count('customer'), orders_sum=Sum('value')).order_by('-orders_sum',)[:5]
```

Then in my templates file, I have the following:

```
{% for customer in top_five_customers %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ customer.customer }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.customer_city }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.orders_count }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.orders_sum }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first filter the related object, and then `Sum` up the `value`, and order it by that value:

```
start_month = date.today().replace(day=1)

Customer.objects.filter(
    order__order_date__gte=start_month
).annotate(
    total=Sum('order__value')
).order_by('-total')[:5]
```

This queryset will thus contain `Customer` objects. The `Customer`s that arise from this `QuerySet` will contain an extra attribute `.total` that is total amount of the orders.

We can slightly boost efficiency since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2) with [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) in which case there is no extra attribute for the `Customer`s:

```
start_month = date.today().replace(day=1)

Customer.objects.filter(
    order__order_date__gte=start_month
).alias(
    total=Sum('order__value')
).order_by('-total')[:5]
```

Comment: Here, I think the year can be a factor. month and year combinedly should be counted.

Comment: @Jafoor: we do that, since we only count orders where the order date is greater than or equal to the first of the current month. If one can not make orders in the future, then we thus each time retrieve only the items in the last month-year combination.

Comment: When I was querying for all time data using the below code I was getting it all right.

Customer.objects.annotate(orders_count=Count('orders'), orders_sum=Sum('orders__value')).order_by('-orders_sum')[:5]

@Willem's answer helped me understand how to apply a filter on my Order model. Now, I'm using below codes to generate data for desired period (let's say for last 90 days):

Customer.objects.filter(orders__order_date__gte=datetime.datetime.now()-timedelta(days=90)).annotate(orders_count=Count('orders'), orders_sum=Sum('orders__value')).order_by('-orders_sum')[:5]

Answer (score 1):

Try to start using SQL views. It easier to dev and maintain.

Comment: Makes sense, but I'm just a beginner in programming and started off with Django. Right now don't want to divert my focus from Django for some time.